# FT230X Baud Rate Aliasing

Tags: uart, ftdi, baudrate

I'm using a FT230X UART, and I'd like to use it with a non-standard baud rate. I came accross this [note](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_120_Aliasing_VCP_Baud_Rates.pdf), explaining that I have to modify the driver file, but even with this documentation I have some trouble.

I'd like to replace the standard rate of 115200 baud with a non-standard one of 125000. I tried to follow the method described in the note but I'm not going anywhere whis this at the moment. Could anyone explain how to do it?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I've seen it in an optical fibre comms system. Some designers just like to use system clocks to derive every clock they use in a system... leaving you with nice non-standard rates.... besides.. why is 115200 a defacto standard rate?

Comment: What is not working for you?... Is it you've followed the steps (Which I think was poorly written if your going from know baud rate to divisor to the .INF file entry )

Comment: I want to do that because I'm writing a firmware for the chip, and I'm setting the baud rate by calculating an integer equal to U2BRG = 4000000/(16 x baudrate) - 1. With 115200 bauds it's equal to 1.17, so the closest int I can use is 1. But if I stick at 115200 bauds with U2BRG = 1, the error is about +/- 8%. That's why I have to alias the 115200 value to 125000, which is the rate I have to apply if U2BRG = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your using the later version for the FTDIPORT.INF file then the answer is to divide 3,000,000 by 125,000 = 24.0 or 18 Hex. So by doing the quick and dirty by looking through the examples of values with no fractional divisors we find.

> 34,00,00,00 => divisor = 52, rate = 57,692
>
> 1A,00,00,00 => divisor = 26, rate = 115,384

Change the entry 1A to 18.

Note you have to reload the drivers (reboot is easier in some cases)

> Also Note:
> The
> current ftdiport.inf file contains both formats for the config data string. You select/disable the
> correct string by using a ; at the start of the
> line to comment out the one you do not want. Only one
> entry for Config Data should be used.)